# GraphQL query based on a specific value of a field

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-api-v4

I want to be able to retrieve the latest release from GitHub for a specific repo using their GraphQL API. To do that, I need to get the latest release where isDraft and isPrerelease are false. I have managed to get the first part, but cant figure out how to do the "where" part of the query.

Here is the basic query I have gotten (https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/):

```
{
  repository(owner: "paolosalvatori", name: "ServiceBusExplorer") {
    releases(first: 1, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
      nodes {
        name
        tagName
        resourcePath
        isDraft
        isPrerelease
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "releases": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "3.0.4",
            "tagName": "3.0.4",
            "resourcePath": "/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases/tag/3.0.4",
            "isDraft": false,
            "isPrerelease": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I cant seem to find a way to do this. Part of the reason is that I am new to GraphQL (first time trying to do a query) and I am not sure how to frame my question.

Can one only "query" based on those types that support arguments (like repository and releases below)? Seems like there should be a way to specify a filter on the field values.

Repository: https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repository/

Releases: https://developer.github.com/v4/object/releaseconnection/

Node: https://developer.github.com/v4/object/release/

Answer (score 8):

> Can one only "query" based on those types that support arguments

Yes: GraphQL doesn't define a generic query language in the same way, say, SQL does.  You can't sort or filter a field result in ways that aren't provided by the server and the application schema.

> I want to be able to retrieve the latest [non-draft, non-prerelease] release from GitHub for a specific repo using their GraphQl API.

As you've already found, [the `releases` field](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#release) on [the `Repository` type](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repository/#releases) doesn't have an option to sort or filter on these fields.  Instead, you can iterate through the releases one at a time with multiple GraphQL calls.  These would individually look like

```graphql
query NextRelease($owner: String!, $name: String!, $after: String) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
    releases(first: 1,
             orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC},
             after: $after) {
      pageInfo { lastCursor }
      nodes { ... ReleaseData } # from the question
    }
  }
}
```

Run this in the same way you're running it now (I've split out the information identifying the repository into separate GraphQL variables).  You can leave off the `after` variable for the first call.  If (as in your example) it returns `"isDraft": false, "isPrerelease": false`, you're set.  If not, you need to try again: take the value from the `lastCursor` in the response, and run the same query, passing that cursor value as the `after` variable value.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  repository(owner: "paolosalvatori", name: "ServiceBusExplorer") {
    releases(first: 1, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
      nodes(isDraft :false , isPrerelease :false ) {
        name
        tagName
        resourcePath
        isDraft
        isPrerelease
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively please have look at GraphQL directives, as sometimes it's required to skip or include the fields on the basis of the values
@skip or @include.

The skip directive, when used on fields or fragments, allows us to exclude fields based on some condition.

The include directive, allows us to include fields based on some condition

[GraphQL Directives](https://medium.com/open-graphql/graphql-directives-3dec6106c384)